# Using Silex with Google Authentication?

Tags: php, google-oauth, silex, google-openid, google-signin

I am tasked with using Silex for a basic web project. I want the user to login to this project.com using Google (and no other method). I have a list of approved gmail accounts in a MySQL database that I want to check against, so only approveduser@gmail.com can login.

How can I integrate Google Sign-In with the Silex framework? I'm not sure how it would interact with [Silex's authorization service provider.](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html) There doesn't seem to be much documentation as far as Silex+Google Sign-In goes, and many old answers are deprecated. Furthermore, how can I check against the emails in my database during this authentication process? I'm new to Silex and only familiar with the basics, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/t-keller/GoogleAuthenticatorProvider ?

Comment: This seems to be for interaction with the Google Authenticator mobile app, so I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. Basically I want to implement the Google Sign-In button using Silex, and then check their account against a database I have.

Comment: I've used [this OpenID Provider](https://github.com/gigablah/silex-oauth) with success